# Save file from mysql database to file system

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing some doc files in a mysql database that need to be saved to the file system and manipulated, however some of the documents are not opening after saving to the file system.

I am pulling the file from the database as follows:

```
 $load_doc = "SELECT doc_id, `doc_ext`, doc_size, `doc_conten` 
              FROM `li_webs_trans`.`li_docs`  WHERE `doc_id`  = '$doc_id'";
 $doc = mysql_query($load_doc) or die(mysql_error());
 $fp = fopen("/var/www/OCR/temp_doc/preview__".$doc_id .".docx", "w+");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($doc)){
     fwrite($fp, $row['doc_conten']);
     }
```

The doc_content filed is a Long BLOB. The files are all docx files.
Any idea why some files open fine but others don't?

Comment: Why not saving the file's full path? So then you get it in your query... add the error you get

Comment: Is the `doc_conten` a `BLOB`? And do not use `mysql_` functions because they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead. Also avoid sql injection by escaping your variables.

Comment: Nobody can guess what's wrong with the resulting files. Judging by the `mysql_` usage, it's likely misescaping. Do a binary diff.

Comment: Are these text files or binary?

Comment: thanks @lolka_bolka, I am working on converting everything over, just not fully done with the mysqli change.  The doc_content is a blob.

Comment: @Mawg these are docx files.

Comment: @mario But the files come out just fine if I download them directly from the webserver using my normal download script.